# Disable SendButton after click on it

Tags: visualforce, javascript, button, custom

I want the Send Button on a visualforce page to disappear after the user clicks on it. How can this be done? I tried the javascript you can see between the script tags but it didn't work!

This is my page:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Edition__c" extensions="MyCtrl">
    <apex:pagemessages />
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock id="IdPB">
            <apex:pageblocksection columns="1" title="Message1" collapsible="false" html-style="font-size: 20px; ">
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Edition__c.Data_Send__c}" rendered="false"/>
            </apex:pageblocksection>
            <apex:pageblockbuttons location="bottom" id="bottoni">
                <apex:commandbutton action="{!Send}" value="Send" style="width: 200px; height: 50px; font-size: 20px;" onclick="DisableSendButton();" />
                <apex:commandbutton action="{!Return}" value="Return" style="width: 200px; height: 50px; font-size: 20px; " />
            </apex:pageblockbuttons>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
    <apex:pagemessages />
    <script>
        function DisableSendButton() {
            document.getElementById(Send).onclick = function() {
                this.disabled = true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the button by changing `display` property to `none` through JavaScript in onclick property:

```
<apex:pagemessages id="pageMessage"/>
<apex:commandbutton action="{!Send}" 
    value="Send" 
    style="width: 200px; height: 50px; font-size: 20px;" 
    onclick="this.style.display = 'none'" 
    rerender="pageMessage"/>
```

Comment: Yes,It works!but when I click Send Button the page reload and the button is visible again. How can I keep the button hidden also after the reload?

Comment: set rerender property to stop reloading, check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

In the function `DisableSendButton` you are binding click event not; To disable the button on click do like this:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Edition__c" extensions="MyCtrl">
    <apex:pagemessages />
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock id="IdPB">

    <apex:pageblocksection columns="1" title="Message1" collapsible="false" html-style="font-size: 20px; ">
            <apex:inputfield value="{!Edition__c.Data_Send__c}" rendered="false"/>
            </apex:pageblocksection>
            <apex:pageblockbuttons location="bottom" id="bottoni">

                <apex:commandbutton action="{!Send}" value="Send" style="width: 200px; height: 50px; font-size: 20px;" onclick="DisableSendButton(this);" />
                <apex:commandbutton action="{!Return}" value="Return" style="width: 200px; height: 50px; font-size: 20px; " />

            </apex:pageblockbuttons>


        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
    <apex:pagemessages />
    <script>
        function DisableSendButton(btn){
            btn.disabled = true;
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It still doesn't work! Any other idea? Maybe the ctrl code could help?